# SQL Server 2008 Mgmt Studio : Incorrect syntax near anything using subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax, subquery

I run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Client
);
```

and I should get a list of all fields in client, instead I get

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Line 4: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

The only reason I've come across this was writing a view with a WITH clause and it gave me the same errors.  Prior to this, SQL Server Management Studio 2005 was uninstalled, and 2008 Management Studio Express was installed in its place.

Any idea why I cannot do a subquery of any kind?  Tried this with New Query and through SELECT TOP 1000 ROWS from Client table.

Comment: These are derived tables BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign an alias to the inner query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Client) AS i
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Client
)A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just

```
SELECT * FROM Client
```

and

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Client
```

if you want to limit the number of rows returned

If your query is more complicated you could use a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Comment: Most likely his actual query is more complicated, but he provided a simplified version for his question.

Comment: Yes, more complex.  I was going to 'settle' with the results using a subquery since the CTE would not evaluate only to find that I forgot to alias it.  The CTE however is still broken and I'm not sure why.  Invalid Syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Even after making it as simple as possible it simply will not evaluate any sql using a CTE.