# The multipart identifier couldn't be bound when make difference between two values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this simple SQL statement:

```
select Expr1.value - Expr2.value FROM
(SELECT
Expr1 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1),
Expr2 = (SELECT COUNT(ID_) FROM Table1 WHERE (UPDATED > CREATED))
)
```

It throws me the errors:

> The multi-part identifier 'Expr1.value' could not be bound
>   The multi-part identifier 'Expr2.value' could not be bound

Where is my mistake ?

I read in Stackoverflow but many topics refer to INNER JOIN statements only. I am looking for to do difference between `Expr1` and `Expr2`. (and show the result)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?  Because the OP was making a mistake and asked how to resolve it?  99% of questions on SO are about "I'm doing X wrong and I don't know how ot fix it", that's the point of SO! *(+1 to compensate)*

Comment: Many users downvoted without explanation. So, What can I do ? Thx Dems for upvote :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
select Expr1 - Expr2 FROM
(
    SELECT
    Expr1 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1),
    Expr2 = (SELECT COUNT(ID_) FROM Table1 WHERE (UPDATED > CREATED))
) as t
```

This:

```
SELECT
    Expr1 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1),
    Expr2 = (SELECT COUNT(ID_) FROM Table1 WHERE (UPDATED > CREATED))
```

returns result set with columns named `Expr1` and `Expr2` and this way you should refer to them. Anyway I prefer `as` for aliasing columns:

```
select Expr1 - Expr2 FROM
(
    SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1) as Expr1,
    (SELECT COUNT(ID_) FROM Table1 WHERE (UPDATED > CREATED)) Expr2
) as t
```

Comment: What does mean `t` at end of first SELECT statment ?

Comment: @MichaelSwan `t` is an alias of subquery, without it you will get an syntax error, e.g.: [Incorrect syntax near anything using subquery at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997132/sql-server-2008-mgmt-studio-incorrect-syntax-near-anything-using-subquery). I've added `as` for clarity :-).