# Select subset of rows using Row_Number() 

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, row-number

```
Select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id asc) as 'RowNo'
from customers
where RowNo between 50 AND 60
```

I am trying to select a subset of rows between 50 and 60 . The problem is 'RowNo' is an invalid column name.

Thank you

Using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Please don't use `'string delimiters'` for aliases. This syntax is non-standard, can be very confusing (e.g. `SELECT 'a' 'b'`), and is  deprecated in SQL Server. Use `[square brackets]` (also not standard), or `"double quotes"` (standard), or no delimiters. For more info and lots of debate see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases.aspx

Comment: P.S. the debate is about what you *should* use. There is little argument that single quotes *should not* be used.

Comment: @Aaron: thnx, I wasn't sure if this was deprecated or not allowed in latest version.

Comment: @ypercube It still works in current versions but it does raise deprecated warning events (trace/perfmon). Well, only certain forms raise deprecated events but that's a different story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use your query as subquery like bellow:

```
select * from (
    Select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id asc) as [RowNo]
    from customers
) t
where RowNo between 50 AND 60
```

You can use CTE as well but whether to choose one over another read [Difference between CTE and SubQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706972/difference-between-cte-and-subquery) and check execution plan.

Comment: thank you! I don't know why you need to perform such a complicated query when in mysql you just use LIMIT 49, 10! can you please tell me why we had to write 't'?

Comment: @test: Because SQL-Server has no `LIMIT x OFFSET y`, like MySQL does. It has only `TOP n` which is the same as MySQL's `LIMIT n`.

Comment: But with analytic functions that it does have, like the `ROWN_NUMBER()` and others, you can do much more complicated things (that are really hard to do in MySQL).

Comment: @test SQL Server 2012 implements the *standard* method for paging (`OFFSET`/`FETCH`). Sure, MySQL is simple, but it's non-standard. I blogged about it here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/10/sql-server-11-denali-using-the-offset-clause.aspx

Comment: @test `t` is an alias for subquery without it you'll get an error (you can try it). More about it [Incorrect syntax near anything using subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997132/sql-server-2008-mgmt-studio-incorrect-syntax-near-anything-using-subquery).

Comment: @Aaron: Come on, I like that SQL-Server implements (at last!) the standard for `FETCH n ROWS` but you can't argue that some other SQL-product is non-standard, implying not as good. `TOP n` is non-standard, too, and many SQL-Server users will not upgrade to 2012 version.

Comment: @ypercube I'm all for proprietary extensions to the language, but if there's something already defined in the standard, I'd rather see that implemented than defining your own syntax. I have plenty of complaints about SQL Server's cowboy choices (like `TIMESTAMP`) but in this case MySQL did it wrong.

Comment: I certainly agree with that. But MySQL had that working long time ago. Not sure if the `FETCH` syntax was in the standard at the time that `LIMIT` and `TOP` were intoduced.

Comment: Well, `TOP` isn't used just for paging, it actually has multiple uses already.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do something like this:

```
;WITH PaginatingData AS
(
    Select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id asc) as 'RowNo'
    from customers
)
SELECT *
FROM PaginatingData
where RowNo between 50 AND 60
```

Use a CTE (Common Table Expression - sort of an "inline view") as a "wrapper" so that your `RowNo` becomes a valid column name.

As an outlook - with SQL Server 2012, you'd be able to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, name
FROM 
    dbo.customers
ORDER BY
    id
OFFSET 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

SQL Server 2012 will have this ANSI SQL Standard compliant notation to do paging directly based on an `ORDER BY` clause. [See this blog post](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) (or tons of others) for more info and more samples.

Comment: `AS RowNo` does not need quotes: `'RowNo'`, does it?

Comment: @ypercube It doesn't, but it isn't wrong either. It's just less common syntax to see with T-SQL.

Comment: @ypercube: I don't think there's absolutely necessary - I just left it as the OP had posted it. Personally, I would use the `RowNo = ROW_NUMBER().....`  notation - but that's just personal style

Comment: @ypercube, yuck and marc, please see my comment to the question (which I left before I saw these comments). I realize marc just copied the OP's code but while the syntax isn't wrong today it will be wrong in a future version of SQL Server.